# SqlCommand cannot be sent in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I insert a new personnel, that function gives me an exception.

What should I do?

```
public void InsertPersonnel(string conStr, string comQuery;)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(comQuery);

    con.open();

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();   // This line throws an exception
}
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Have you set connection string and parameters properly? Please give your insert query statement.

Comment: At least you should tell the ADO that this command must be run on this connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify the command's connection property. There are two ways to specify the connection.

**1st option**

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(comQuery, con);
```

**2nd option**

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(comQuery);

com.Connection = con;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the second way and it worked.